# How do i save to a text file on my iphone app

Tags: iphone, email, xcode4

I have an app which is almost finished and the last part is where I send the data collected via email to the respondent. I know if I use a file in my bundle I can't write to it as it will be readonly. Where else can I save my file to that I can then use the path for my email attatchment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only write to your application's sand-boxed documents directory. Try using this:

```
NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

`documentsDir` gives you the complete path as a string to your applications documents directory.

And then you can either use `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` or

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

to write your data to the location.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file in `DocumentDirectory`...  which is accessible via below code

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.abc", @"userdata"]];
```

refer for more detail : [iphone: How to add Email functionality in iPhone Ebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636142/iphone-how-to-add-email-functionality-in-iphone-ebook-app/8637604#8637604)